# Max from one query as condition for another query

Tags: sql-server

I retrieve max date from table A and now I want to retrieve all records from table B which have date later than max data from table A. This is for SQL Server, if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM B
WHERE B.[date]>(SELECT max([date]) FROM A)
```

Comment: So simple, I cannot believe it. Thank you!